# How to pass a multidimensional hash as query parameters using retrofit by Square

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a map of string id's and points, from which I need to generate a path similar to this:

```
.../?assessment[id_1][points]=3&assessment[id_2][points]=5
```

I'm not exactly sure how i would do something like this in retrofit.
I've tried manually generating a string and appending it to the end of a request

```
@PUT("/path/to/api/{assessment}?{}")
    void postScore(@Path("assessment") String rubricAssessment, Callback<Submission> callback);
```

Which is pretty hacky and results in the error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Inteface.postScore: URL query string "{assessment}" must not have replace block.
```

Could someone suggest a better method of accomplishing this in retrofit?

Thank you for reading my question.

EDIT:

One possible solution i've found is to use either a QueryMap or a FieldMap, but that still requires me to create a helper method to manually construct each key value. Something like this:

```
 private static String getFieldMap(Map<String,String> map){
    Map<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())) {
        map.put("assessment[" +entry.getCriterionId() +"][points]", String.valueOf(entry.getPoints()));
    }
    return fieldMap;
}
```

Then passing that map into something like this?

```
 @put("/things")
 void things(@FieldMap Map<String, String> fields);
 }
```

Is that the best way to do this? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I have this same question, too. According to this discussion https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/490, seems like retrofit doesn't support the nested query/field. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. You can indeed use a `QueryMap`. To be honest never tried using a `FieldMap` since `QueryMap` works perfectly fine for me.

If you want to use queryMap it is very simple. Example:

```
Map testMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    testMap.put("key1", "value1");
    testMap.put("key2", "value2");
```

And pass it to you postScore call.

```
something.postScore("yourStringValue",testMap);
```

Your retrofit call should look something like this:

```
void postScore(@Path("assessment") String rubricAssessment, @QueryMap Map<String,String> callback)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why the type of the callback of the last expression is `Map<String, String>`? It should be a `Callback`, right?